# unrecognized selector sent to instance - XCode 9.4.1, Swift 4.0

Tags: swift, xcode9.4

I'm working through the Stanford [Swift Course iOS9 from 2016](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mlwwEEJm3dI&t=3312s) and having trouble replicating a UIPinchGestureRecognizer, getting very confused with the Selector code syntax.

Inside Class FaceViewController in FaceViewConroller.Swift:

```
@IBOutlet weak var faceView: FaceView! {
    didSet {
        faceView.addGestureRecognizer(UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(changeScale(_:))))
        updateUI()
    }
}
```

Inside Class definition of Faceview in FaceView.Swift:

```
@objc
func changeScale(_ recognizer: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
    switch recognizer.state {
    case .changed,.ended:
        scale *= recognizer.scale
        recognizer.scale = 1.0
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

It builds without an error (which took a while) but when it runs the pinch gesture causes an error:

> Faceit.FaceViewController changeScale:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have passed the wrong `target` parameter.

Since the method you want to call (`changeScale`) is declared in `FaceView`, the target should be an instance of `FaceView`, not `FaceViewController`, since `FaceViewController` does not have a `changeScale` method.

So:

```
faceView.addGestureRecognizer(UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: faceView, action: #selector(changeScale(_:))))
```